# Is there another API that will enable real-time audio processing on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, real-time

I was hoping to make an application that did real time voice manipulation like the the T-Pain App.  But AVAudioRecorder only enables a post processing from of audio manipulation. Is there another API that will enable real-time audio processing?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The iOS Audio Unit RemoteIO API allows for very low latency audio recording and playback, and the raw audio sample buffers are available for modification in between the audio record and play buffer callbacks.

See Apple's aurioTouch sample app for example source code.